# Nugets packages from .net Standard 2.0 projects not showing in NuGet packages tab in TeamCity

Tags: nuget, teamcity, teamcity-8.0

We have a .net solution that contains .net standard 2.0 projects and .net framework projects.

On each build with TeamCity we have a step with NuGet Installer to restore the nuget packages for solution (nuget version 4.3.0). The step works fine, it restores the nuget packages but on Nuget Packages tab at Used Packages section we see only the nugets from .net framework projects.

Only the .net framework projects have packages.config file, the .net standard 2.0 ones doesn't have this files because nuget package manager uses PackageReference by default (as stated here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files) so the nugets used are included in .csproj files.

What can be done in order for nuget packages for .net standard 2.0 projects show up on on Nuget Packages tab at Used Packages section ?

Thank you,

Adriana

Answer (score 0):

Seems is a known issue of TeamCity, and if we need it fixed we should vote for it here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-52327

If anyone else has a workaround till is fixed please post it :)